# Spring security cannot match password

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, bcrypt

I have following spring security configuration:

```
<authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager">
        <!-- <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService"> -->
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                users-by-username-query="select email,password,prop_was_moderated from terminal_user where email = ? and prop_confirm_terminal=true"
                authorities-by-username-query="select email,user_role from terminal_user where email = ?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
    </beans:bean>
```

and following configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class Configiuration {
    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I create user password like this:

```
 ...
  @Autowired
  private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
  ...
  public void register(...){
     ...
     user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(generatedPassword));
     ...
  }
  ...
```

But when I try to loging I seemessage that auth failed.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Could you please share debug logs generated by Spring Security? Did you compare the hash you can find in your database for the particular password with a hash generated on the fly in a unittest? Do they match?

Comment: Where can I change spring security log severity?

Comment: I have not unit tests

Comment: It depends on your logging library. In `logback` use  `<logger name="org.springframework.security" additivity="false" level="OFF"><appender-ref ref="..." /></logger>` where `...` should be replaced with a appender (file or console). In log4j use `log4j.logger.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG, ...` where `...` should be replaced with a appender (file or console).

Comment: Write a simple unittest that verifies whether generated hash for a given password is equal to a hash for a known password from your database.

Comment: @ksokol Won't work. BCrypt uses random salt.

Comment: @holmis83 I know. But I'm thinking of `assertTrue(bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches("test", "$2a$10$BoMiPD6HyLkb5ZW9fwqScu26p1UatJa/5CcebRCrgs5tKpRVceJna"));`. I would like to know whether stored hash in database wasn't e.g. truncated (I'm looking at you, MySQL).

Comment: @ksokol I see. Good clarification.